# Jenkins Pipeline - Codeception Test publishHTML - No HTML displays

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, codeception

I have a Jenkins pipeline that builds a docker instance bringing up a Symfony project, which works fine.  We use codeception for testing, and I wanted to add that to the pipeline, and have the codecoverage for each build display in Jenkins.

The pipeline runs successfully, and the testing passes and generates HTML, and the publishHTML step seems to succeed, but nothing displays in the Jenkins UI. (I'm not even sure where to look, as it merely says "in the dashboard" in the documentation).

The relevant part of the pipeline:

```
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        ansiColor('xterm') {
            sh 'ssh jenkins@10.90.0.211 "sudo docker exec broccoli_app_1 ./vendor/bin/codecept run unit --env edge --coverage-html"'  
        }
      }
    }
  }
  post {
      always {
          echo 'Running post build script to publish report'
          publishHTML([allowMissing: true, alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true, keepAll: true, reportDir: 'broccoli/tests/_output/coverage/', reportFiles: 'index.html', reportName: "HTML Report", reportTitles: "Coverage Report"])
      }
  }
```

And in the console, it returns what seem to be non-failing messages:

```
[Pipeline] echo
Running post build script to publish report
[Pipeline] publishHTML
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at BUILD level /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/broccoli2stage/broccoli/tests/_output/coverage to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/broccoli2stage/builds/56/htmlreports/HTML_20Report
[Pipeline] }
```

Is there any other config that I'm missing?

Comment: Usually there will be a link in the sidebar of that job which you can click to show the html. I’m cannot recall whether it was in the job run or in the job itself, though.

Comment: That's about what I was thinking based on seeing a few limited screenshots, but I can't find such a link anywhere after the build.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually got this to work.  I don't think my solution will necessarily apply to many cases.

You can see in this line, we were logging into a seperate server to run the test:

```
 sh 'ssh jenkins@10.90.0.211 "sudo docker exec broccoli_app_1 ./vendor/bin/codecept run unit --env edge --coverage-html"'
```

So publishHTML didn't have access to the code run results.  Turns out we didn't need to do that with our setup for this build, so just running it locally got it to work.

```
 sh 'sudo docker exec broccoli_app_1 codecept run unit --env edge --coverage-html'
```